# Cleaning out tweet json file using python

Tags: python, json, twitter

I have twitter json file and want to extract specific info from here. Example of this json file can be found here, https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/intro-to-tweet-json

```
{
    "created_at": "Thu Apr 06 15:24:15 +0000 2017",
    "id_str": "850006245121695744",
    "text": "1\/ Today we\u2019re sharing our vision for the future of the Twitter API platform!\nhttps:\/\/t.co\/XweGngmxlP",
    "user": {
      "id": 2244994945,
      "name": "Twitter Dev",
      "screen_name": "TwitterDev",
      "location": "Internet",
      "url": "https:\/\/dev.twitter.com\/",
      "description": "Your official source for Twitter Platform news, updates & events. Need technical help? Visit https:\/\/twittercommunity.com\/ \u2328\ufe0f #TapIntoTwitter"
    },
    "place": {

    },
    "entities": {
      "hashtags": [

      ],
      "urls": [
        {
          "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/XweGngmxlP",
          "unwound": {
            "url": "https:\/\/cards.twitter.com\/cards\/18ce53wgo4h\/3xo1c",
            "title": "Building the Future of the Twitter API Platform"
          }
        }
      ],
      "user_mentions": [

      ]
    }
  }
```

I tried to remove some item that I don't need, like `id_str`.
So I created a list that holds the name of keys I need, and iterate this json file(one file has more than a million tweets). I already searched similar questions and tried to implement what replies suggest.

```
tags = ["created_at", "text", "retweet_count",
        "friends_count","followers_count","verified","place"]
for line in json_file:
    try:
        data = json.loads(line)
        for i in data.keys():
            if i not in tags:
                try:
                    del data[i]
                except:
                    continue
    except:
        continue

for line in json_file:
    data = json.loads(line)
    print(data)
```

However, my json_file is empty, it does not print out anything at the final.
Instead of `del data[i]` I tried multiple different ways like

```
del data[str(i)]
data.pop(i)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Editing the Python data structure won't alter the file data, you need to serialise back to JSON and write to a new file. Next, you are reading from your file *twice*, the second time around you didn't seek back to the file start, the file position is still at the end so no more data is read for that second loop.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If it does not alter file data, doesn't it still have to print out?

Comment: That's where the second part of my comment comes in. Add `json_file.seek(0)` to go back to the start of the file.

Comment: You really should not be catching all exceptions. Catch *specific* exceptions only, we can't even tell if your data is loaded correctly each iteration.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah true. and that tweet example is just example from twitter's website, not my code. Since my file is crawled from the web, I don't post it here. But thank you for advice

Answer (score -1):

You need to read the json file at once using `json.loads()`
All the tags appear one level below in `data["tweets"]`

```
import json

json_file = open("test.json").read()
tags = ["created_at", "text", "retweet_count", "friends_count","followers_count","verified","place"]

data = json.loads(json_file)

for i in data["tweet"].keys():
    if i not in tags:
        del data["tweet"][i] 

print data
```

Comment: They have a [JSON lines file](http://jsonlines.org/), so no, they don't need to read the file at once. This is not the problem they are facing. See [Loading and parsing a JSON file with multiple JSON objects in Python](//stackoverflow.com/q/12451431)

Comment: Considering the example json they have given it doesn't seem so.

Also, the tweet parameter is important.

Also, one can dump it into another file.

Comment: The example *code* they have given doesn't throw an exception, and it can *only work if the data is JSON lines formatted*.

Comment: It is ambigious. 
I assumed the code was incorrectly reading each line as a json where only the entire file was a json.